# Llenar array bidimensional con objetos

Tags: java

tengo que replicar una array bidimensional que dejo a continuacion...gracias

1 'A' 1'B' 1'C'  1'D' 1'E'  1'F' 
2 'A' 2'B' 2'C' 2'D' 2'E'  2'F' 
Y así hasta 10...

La matriz tiene que ser de tipo Objeto y estos rangos [30][6].

Dejo la clase del objeto

```js
public class Seient {

 
 int fila;
 char column;
 boolean ocupat = false;
 
 
 public Seient(int fila, char column) {
  super();
  this.fila = fila;
  this.column = column;
 }
```